# Balance weights using backtracking algorithm in Swift

Tags: swift, algorithm, backtracking

I'm trying to implement a solution using the backtracking algorithm.

I have some weights `[1,2,7,10,20,70,100,200,700...]` and I want to return the weights after a given input/

For example input => `12` should return `[2,10]`
For example input => `8` should return  `[1,7]`

My code seem's not to work well. It works only for some input numbers  like `13` or `8`

```
for targetValue in [13] {
    var currentValue = 0
    var usedWeights: [Int] = []
    for weight in weights {
        if targetValue > weight {
            currentValue += weight
            usedWeights.append(weight)
        } else if weight > targetValue {
            let rememberLast = usedWeights.last ?? 0
            usedWeights.remove(at: usedWeights.count-1)
            currentValue -= rememberLast
            if currentValue > targetValue || currentValue < targetValue {
                let last = usedWeights.remove(at: usedWeights.count-1)
                currentValue -= last
                usedWeights.append(rememberLast)
                currentValue -= rememberLast
            print(usedWeights) /// [1, 2, 10] Yeah it work's :) but only for some number ..:(
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The used weights should be unique.

I have some trouble to find the weights.

This is how the algorithm work
Input => 13 
1
1+2
1+2+7
1+2+7+10 //currentValue is now 20
1+2+7   // still no solution get the last removed element and remove the current last element
1+2+10   // Correct weights

I hope you can help me and I explain what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: It's a balance weight and I'm trying to solve it with backtracking @user770

Comment: Iterate backwards. For each value less than or equal to the current total, add that number and subtract from the total. Continue until you reach zero. But what about totals such as 15? You can't get 15 from the values you have without doubling some values.

Comment: Yeah correct @rmaddy I'm trying to do it first with small number just for testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one solution. Iterate in reverse through the weights. If the weight is less than or equal to the current total, use the weight.

```
let weights = [1,2,7,10,20,70,100,200,700] // the weights you have
let needed = 12 // The total weight you want

var total = needed // The current working total
var needs = [Int]() // The resulting weights needed
for weight in weights.reversed() {
    if weight <= total {
        needs.append(weight)
        total -= weight
    }
}
if total == 0 {
    print("Need \(needs) for \(needed)")
} else {
    print("No match for \(needed)")
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This will help me to understand the whole algorithm better. But this is not really backtracking right?

Comment: If more than one weight is allowed you can use `while weight <= total {` instead of `if weight <= total {`

Comment: Thank you @LeoDabus but I really like the solution from rmaddy, because this will return the optimal weights. For 10 => [10] and not [1,2,7]. Cool trick to loop reverse. :)

Comment: @BilalReffas you didn't understand my comment if you use `while` instead of `if` it would return `[10, 2, 2, 1]` for `15` instead of `"No match for 15\n"`

Comment: Ouh @LeoDabus that's true.. it don't work for 15.. but I need unique weights. That's the hard thing.. :( but 15 will anyway not work with these weights.

Comment: @LeoDabus I think your solution will create a not ending loop

Comment: I have tested it here and it worked as expected. Can you show what condition would result in an endless loop?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you set the weight.
But consider:

```
[2,3,6,10,20]
and needed = 21
```

Then the algorithm will not find it (no match), when there is a solution obviously: 2 + 3 + 6 + 10

So, you should call recursively the search algorithm when it fails, after removing from the weights the first you picked.

This is not very clean, but seem to work (in code, some issue in playground)

```
func searchIt(weightsSearch: [Int], neededSearch: Int) -> (needs: [Int], remainingWeights: [Int], found: Bool) {
    var total = neededSearch // The current working total
    var needs = [Int]() // The resulting weights needed
    var remaining = weightsSearch
    var firstNotYetSelected = true
    var position = weightsSearch.count - 1
    for weight in weightsSearch.reversed() {
        if weight <= total {
            needs.append(weight)
            total -= weight
            if firstNotYetSelected {
                remaining.remove(at : position)
            }
            firstNotYetSelected = false
            position -= 1
        }
    }
return (needs, remaining, total == 0)
}

var needs = [Int]() // The resulting weights needed
var remainingWeights = weights
var foundIt: Bool
repeat {
    (needs, remainingWeights, foundIt) = searchIt(weightsSearch: remainingWeights, neededSearch: needed)
    if foundIt {
        print("Need \(needs) for \(needed)")
        break
    } else {
        print("No match yet for \(needed)")
    }
} while remainingWeights.count >= 1
```

with the test case

```
let weights = [2,3,6,10,20] 
let needed = 21
```

we get

```
No match yet for 21
Need [10, 6, 3, 2] for 21
```

If you want ALL the solutions, replace break statement by continue.

With the test case

```
let weights = [2,3,6,10,15,20] 
let needed = 21
```

we get the 2 solutions

```
No match for 21
No match for 21
Need [15, 6] for 21
Need [10, 6, 3, 2] for 21
No match for 21
No match for 21
No match for 21
```